# How to convert a NFA to alternating finite automata AFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I am trying to construct an AFA from a NFA, how do I know if a state of NFA becoms existential or universal in the AFA?

Comment: An NFA is a special case of an AFA where all transitions are existential. Thus, a transition $\delta(q,\sigma)=S\subseteq Q$ of an NFA is translated into the transition $\delta'(q,\sigma)=\bigvee_{q\in S}q$ of the corresponding AFA.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so the new AFA will have all states of type existential , correct?

Comment: could you show me an example please, thank you!

Comment: I think that you're considering a model where each state is either "existential" or "universal" - If so then the answer is yes, the corresponding AFA is such that all states are existential. Note that there's another model whether transitions can be any Boolean expression , e.g., $\delta(q,a)=q \wedge (p \lor r)$. This is the model I referred to in my answer, in such model there is no partition between existential and universal states.

Comment: an example of what?